# Environment variables iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, environment-variables

I come from a Ruby on Rails background, where we have the beautiful `Rails.env` variable. As a  new iOS developer I'm wondering how can I set a `development` environment variable for an iOS, or where I could find an existing one.

My current method is to use a macro

`#define DEVELOPMENT 1`

However than I have to manually change this before launching, it doesn't feel clean. I saw that in my build settings there was a slew of environment variables. What is the semantic way to use those to distinguish dev/production?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your project should already include a `DEBUG` preprocessor macro (defined as part of the project template). This is defined in the build settings and only set for the Debug build configuration. You can use this setting and define others if required. Then, when you build for Debug / Release the flags will automatically be enabled / disabled.

You use them like:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    // TEST
#else
    // PRODUCTION
#endif
```

Comment: Something so simple is so narrowly available. Thanks.